# How to get the name of a function added as a listener to a Button's onClick event?

Tags: unity, c#, events

If my button uses AddListener to subscribe a function to listen for clicks:

```
mybutton.onClick.AddListener(getNameFunction);
```

Is there a way to get the name of that listening function (i.e. "getNameFunction" in this example)?

I tried
`onClick.GetPersistentMethodName(0)`, but it does not seem like the right way.

if i add funtcion in onclick list, .GetPersistentMethodName(0) will return the name

[image]

But it does not seem to return the correct result when the function was added using AddListener in the script (e.g. in Start())."

Comment: this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. Can you tell us *why* you need the name of the event handler method? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish what you are *actually* trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are using the normal `AddListener` method when adding your function. Listeners that you add over the editor do not use `AddListener` but `AddPersistentListener`.

As you can already see from the name, it matches the `GetPersistentMethodName`. `GetPersistentEventCount` returns as well 0 for the normal AddListener. You need to change the way how you add it since it is not possible to do it exactly the same way. Luckily there is a tool helper class for it.

```
public Button button;

void Start() {
    UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener(button.onClick, MyClickFunction);
}

public void MyClickFunction() {
    Debug.Log(button.onClick.GetPersistentMethodName(0));
}
```

UnityEventTools is in the UnityEditor namespace and can't be used in the compiled build. Depending on why and for what you need the method name and the option in the editor compared to the normal listener, where you actually include the `UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener` will depend. But you can't leave it in `Start` for your compiled build.

Normal editor
[image: Editor coding]

Runtime:
[image: Runtime]

Answer (score 3):

I felt fancy and decided to answer the actual question. You can do that with some reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class GettingMethodNamesFromUnityEvent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent exampleEvent;

    void Start()
    {
        exampleEvent.AddListener(Foo);
        exampleEvent.AddListener(Bar);
        exampleEvent.AddListener(Baz);

        var mCalls = exampleEvent
            .GetType()
            .BaseType
            .GetField("m_Calls", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(exampleEvent);

        var mRuntimeCalls = mCalls
            .GetType()
            .GetField("m_RuntimeCalls", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(mCalls) as IList;

        var delegateField = mRuntimeCalls[0]
            .GetType()
            .GetField("Delegate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var methodNames = mRuntimeCalls
            .Cast<object>()
            .Select(runtimeCall => delegateField.GetValue(runtimeCall))
            .Cast<MulticastDelegate>()
            .SelectMany(mcDel => mcDel.GetInvocationList())
            .Select(del => del.Method.Name)
            .ToArray();

        Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", methodNames));
    }

    private void Foo()
    {
    }

    private void Bar()
    {
    }

    private void Baz()
    {
    }
}
```

Prints "Foo, Bar, Baz" as expected:

[image]

Please note that this is terrible code, and you should probably never ever use it.